# Swift - что за зверь?

Tags: swift, ios, apple

Несколько минут назад apple представило новый яп - swift. Говорят про него они так: он objective-c without c.

Предлагаю писать сюда всё, что известно о нём. Ну там он динамичный/статичный и т.п.

P.s. [Objective-C](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GuyLy.jpg)

Comment: О, круто, похоже на C# :)

Comment: Уже поперли объявления типа: "Требуется разработчик на  swift, опыт работы - **не менее года**" :)

Comment: @deivan опыт работы может быть хоть 10 лет, то что разработчик изучил swift, ничего не значит относительно опыта.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

На первый взгляд, очень похоже на C#, статически типизированный объектно-ориентированный язык. Вот список того, что есть в C# и появилось в Swift по сравнению с Objective C.

1. Автоматический вывод типов переменных.
2. Лямбды с нормальным синтаксисом, гораздо удобнее, чем блоки.
3. Memory safety и отсутствие wild pointer'ов в качестве бонуса.
4. Дженерики.
5. Циклы наподобие `foreach`.
6. value types и reference types, структуры и классы
7. Функции — объекты первого класса (раз уж есть лямбды...)
8. type safety, отсутствие undefined behaviour
9. Nullable
10. Именованные аргументы функций, out-параметры (отречёмся от старого ми-и-ира!)
11. string interpolation (будет в C# 6)
12. поддержка safe-навигации (будет в C# 6)

Теперь преимущества:

1. Есть `let` — объявление констант внутри тела функции. В C# есть такое лишь в ограниченном контексте (LINQ query syntax). Неясна точная семантика: это deep const или shallow const? Если deep, имеет ли объект право измениться сам по себе?
2. Синтаксическая поддержка инициализации списков, словарей и кортежей.
3. Расширения (extensions) сильнее, чем Extension Methods из C#: добавляются статические методы, а также имплементируются протоколы. (Не знаю, как это соотносится с категориями Objective C.)
4. Delegation — очень похоже на mix-in'ы, хочу такое в C#.
5. Мощнейший `switch` с pattern matching'ом.
6. Вложенные функции! (Надеюсь, они наследуют контекст.)
7. where-constraint в generic'ах мощнее
8. Конструктор базового класса можно вызывать где угодно, не только в начале.
9. AOP-образные `willSet` и `didSet`
10. Укороченный синтаксис для лямбд (`$1` etc.)

Отличия, забавные и серьёзные:

1. Garbage collector'а нету, есть ARC. Ручная расстановка слабых ссылок и проблемы с closure в комплекте.
2. Миленькие trailing closures.
3. Методы по умолчанию виртуальные, как в Java.
4. Массивы и словари — value type, копируются при передаче в качестве параметров.
5. Более правильный порядок записи типов: тип после переменной, тип возвращаемого значения после аргументов
6. Приятная конструкция `if let` для safe navigation.

Чего не увидел:

1. Нет LINQ-образных lazy enumerations
2. `event`'ы? Без них программирование UI не очень удобно.
3. А где исключения? Опять пробрасывать `nil`?
4. Встроенная в язык поддержка многопоточности? Пора бы уже, 2014 год.

Comment: Перенёс про порядок в отличия - всё же спорный момент, вопрос вкуса

Comment: @danpetruk: Более правильные, так как, например, естественно записывается композиция функций: `compose (X -> Y), (Y -> Z) -> (X, Z)`. Если много работать со сложными типами функций, особенно высших порядков, такой порядок получается естественнее и удобнее.

В C# он обратный как тяжёлое наследие синтаксиса C.

Comment: @VladD зато:

    int a //5 символов
    var a : int //11

Comment: @danpetruk: зато:

    char (*x[5])(int); // не понятно никому
    var x: (int -> char)[] // самоочевидно

Comment: Ну, хотя бы фигурные скобочки есть :)

На самом деле все (в судьбе очередного `С+#-...`) будет зависит от доступности хороших бесплатных компиляторов/библиотек на всех массовых платформах.

(зная жлобство манагеров из крупных компаний -- мой прогноз скорее отрицательный (скажем, 10% нового ПО через 5 лет и выход на плато)).

Comment: @avp: Пусть расцветут тысячи цветов. Если бы не было C#, и Java не развивалась бы. Теперь глядишь, и C# подтянется. Так что я доволен, по сути.

И конечно, хотелось бы, чтобы компилятор и среда были доступны. Microsoft, кстати, заопенсорсил новый компилятор C#.

Comment: @VladD, пусть цветут. В начале 60-х их были сотни (в каждом белее-менее крупном ВЦ свои языки. Помню карикатуру в какой-то книжке -- вавилонская башня из ЯВУ).

А вот это

    4. Массивы и словари — value type, копируются при передаче в качестве параметров.

серьезно?

Если да, то представляю, как потирают руки производители железа

(на самом деле это было бы даже хорошо).

Comment: @avp, похоже, мне нужен кэп :) можете прояснить по поводу производителей железа? Почему они должны потирать руки?

Comment: блин, у меня такое чувство что язык создан с миру по нитке - 

var a: int - привет паскаль, давно не виделись

let ... - и тебе привет, basic (я понял что это не переменные, а константы, но все равно не могу отделаться)

(NSData,NSError)->Void={data,error in /*...*/} - erlang? не совсем он вроде, но похоже

ну и конечно видны куски javascript

Comment: @Veikedo, ну как же. 

--

Представьте, Вы передаете массив из 1000000 элементов в какую-нибудь функцию. А передача не по ссылке (как сейчас принято) а по значению.
Т.е. вместо перемещения нескольких байт (указатель или дескриптор (зависит от конструкции языка) в стеке (или даже в регистрах)) надо скопировать несколько мегабайт.

А процессов-то в системе реально много. 

Получается, чтобы машинка работала вообще, память надо будет увеличить на порядок (или на 2). А чтобы она работала шустро придется что-то изобретать с параллелизацией копирования, независимыми банками память и кучей DMA и т.п

Comment: @avp: угу, вот [пруф](http://bit.ly/1pC34kh). Правда, они вроде бы обещали copy-on-write, но я подробно не читал.

Comment: @aknew: думаю, `let` пришёл не из Бейсика, а из функциональных языков. Оттуда же обозначение типов функций `Т1 -> Т2`.

Comment: ну про функции то я и сам понял, даже ерланг упомянул (единственный из функциональных с корторым хоть немного опыта есть), а в целом надо конечно пощупать что за зверь этот свифт

Answer (score 4):

- [Доки](https://developer.apple.com/swift/),
- Книга: [The Swift Programming Language. Apple Inc.](https://itunes.apple.com/us/book/the-swift-programming-language/id881256329?mt=11).

Comment: похоже, эппл изобрел свой qml

Comment: @aknew: qml? У них появился язык разметки? А где почитать?

Comment: Пока не знаю, это было первое впечатление по быстронагугленой информации, уж очень похож подход - интерпретируемый, трансляция в рантайм компилируемого языка, показ как круто на нем быстро писать красивые по интерфейсу приложения. Похоже, предположение неверное

Answer (score 4):

[Всё, что вам нужно знать про Swift](http://levin-matveev.livejournal.com/86543.html) - в принципе достаточно грамотно всё расписано

Comment: Вопрос, я так понимаю, задавался ради смешной картинки и плюсиков?

Comment: @Fike неа, плюсиков я вообще не ожидал. Скорее ради новой метки + удобнее читать мнения других, чем сухую документацию

Comment: Ради новой метки. О господи.